Proving that Player A Wins the Game with Probability $p$
A and B play a game consisting of $2k - 1$ matches for $k \ge 1$. The first player to win $k$ matches wins the game. If A and B have won the same number of matches, then in the next match, the probability that A wins is $p$. If A and B have won different numbers of matches, then the player who has won fewer matches wins the next match with probability $p$. Prove that the probability that A wins the game is $p$.
My attempts:
Let $P(a, b)$ denote the probability that A wins the game given that A has won $a$ matches and B has won $b$ matches so far.
\begin{aligned}
P(k, b) &= 1 \quad \text{for } 0 \leq b < k \\
P(a, k) &= 0 \quad \text{for } 0 \leq a < k \\
P(a, a) &= p \, P(a+1, a) + (1-p) \, P(a, a+1) \quad \text{for } 0 \leq a < k \\
P(a, b) &= p \, P(a+1, b) + (1-p) \, P(a, b+1) \quad \text{for } 0 \leq a < b < k \\
P(a, b) &= (1-p) \, P(a+1, b) + p \, P(a, b+1) \quad \text{for } 0 \leq b < a < k
\end{aligned}
I've checked using Mathematica for $k=3,4,5,6$ and found it's correct. However, I cannot have easy intuition why it's true.  How to prove this with easy argument?
k = 6;
eqn = Flatten[{Table[
     P[i, i] == p  P[i + 1, i] + (1 - p)  P[i, i + 1], {i, 0, k - 1}],
     Table[P[k, i] == 1, {i, 0, k - 1}], 
    Table[P[i, k] == 0, {i, 0, k - 1}], 
    Table[{P[i, j] == p  P[i + 1, j] + (1 - p)  P[i, j + 1], 
      P[j, i] == (1 - p)  P[j + 1, i] + p  P[j, i + 1]}, {i, 0, 
      k - 2}, {j, i + 1, k - 1}]}];
var = Flatten[
   Table[If[i != k || j != k, P[i, j], Nothing], {i, 0, k}, {j, 0, 
     k}]];
sol = Solve[eqn, var]

{{P[0, 0] -> p, 
  P[0, 1] -> 
   p^2 + p^3 + p^4 + p^5 + p^6 - 41 p^7 + 79 p^8 - 56 p^9 + 14 p^10, 
  P[0, 2] -> p^3 + 2 p^4 + 3 p^5 + 4 p^6 - 37 p^7 + 42 p^8 - 14 p^9, 
  P[0, 3] -> p^4 + 3 p^5 + 6 p^6 - 18 p^7 + 9 p^8, 
  P[0, 4] -> p^5 + 4 p^6 - 4 p^7, P[0, 5] -> p^6, P[0, 6] -> 0, 
  P[1, 0] -> 1 - p + 42 p^6 - 120 p^7 + 135 p^8 - 70 p^9 + 14 p^10, 
  P[1, 1] -> p, 
  P[1, 2] -> p^2 + p^3 + p^4 + p^5 - 13 p^6 + 15 p^7 - 5 p^8, 
  P[1, 3] -> p^3 + 2 p^4 + 3 p^5 - 10 p^6 + 5 p^7, 
  P[1, 4] -> p^4 + 3 p^5 - 3 p^6, P[1, 5] -> p^5, P[1, 6] -> 0, 
  P[2, 0] -> 
   1 - p^2 - p^3 - p^4 - p^5 + 41 p^6 - 79 p^7 + 56 p^8 - 14 p^9, 
  P[2, 1] -> 1 - p + 14 p^5 - 28 p^6 + 20 p^7 - 5 p^8, P[2, 2] -> p, 
  P[2, 3] -> p^2 + p^3 + p^4 - 4 p^5 + 2 p^6, 
  P[2, 4] -> p^3 + 2 p^4 - 2 p^5, P[2, 5] -> p^4, P[2, 6] -> 0, 
  P[3, 0] -> 1 - p^3 - 2 p^4 - 3 p^5 + 24 p^6 - 27 p^7 + 9 p^8, 
  P[3, 1] -> 1 - p^2 - p^3 - p^4 + 13 p^5 - 15 p^6 + 5 p^7, 
  P[3, 2] -> 1 - p + 5 p^4 - 6 p^5 + 2 p^6, P[3, 3] -> p, 
  P[3, 4] -> p^2 + p^3 - p^4, P[3, 5] -> p^3, P[3, 6] -> 0, 
  P[4, 0] -> 1 - p^4 - 3 p^5 + 8 p^6 - 4 p^7, 
  P[4, 1] -> 1 - p^3 - 2 p^4 + 6 p^5 - 3 p^6, 
  P[4, 2] -> 1 - p^2 - p^3 + 4 p^4 - 2 p^5, 
  P[4, 3] -> 1 - p + 2 p^3 - p^4, P[4, 4] -> p, P[4, 5] -> p^2, 
  P[4, 6] -> 0, P[5, 0] -> 1 - p^5 + p^6, P[5, 1] -> 1 - p^4 + p^5, 
  P[5, 2] -> 1 - p^3 + p^4, P[5, 3] -> 1 - p^2 + p^3, 
  P[5, 4] -> 1 - p + p^2, P[5, 5] -> p, P[5, 6] -> 0, P[6, 0] -> 1, 
  P[6, 1] -> 1, P[6, 2] -> 1, P[6, 3] -> 1, P[6, 4] -> 1, 
  P[6, 5] -> 1}}

From above result, we can see that $P(i,i)=p$ for $0\le i < k$.

We divide the matches into $4$ classes:

Class $A$: Matches where before the match the score is tied, and after the match $A$ is ahead by $1$.
Class $B$: Matches where before the match the score is tied, and after the match $B$ is ahead by $1$.
Class $X$: Matches where before the match one player is ahead, and the player who is ahead wins.
Class $Y$: Matches where before the match one player is behind, and the player who is behind wins.

The outcome of the game can be determined by listing (in order) the class that each of the $2k-1$ matches belong to.   Note that not all sequences are valid here -- for example, a the first match is either class $A$ or $B$, and in a game beginning $(A,X \dots$) the next match is also an $X/Y$ match.  However, we have the following observations.

If a sequence is valid and a game follows the sequence, the winner is whatever appears last among $A$ and $B$.
There is a bijection between valid sequences where $A$ wins and valid sequences where $B$ wins, formed by finding the last term in the sequence which is either $A$ or $B$, and swapping it to the other one from $\{A,B\}$.
If a sequence is valid, its probability is $p^{|A|+|Y|}(1-p)^{|B|+|X|}$ (where $|A|$ denotes the number of $A$'s in the sequence and similarly).

In particular, for each pair in the bijection, the "$A$ wins" sequence has probability $\frac{p}{1-p}$ times the "B wins" sequence.  So the overall probability of $A$ winning is $\frac{p}{1-p}$ times the probability $B$ wins, and the result follows.
